# Node.js Configure Error: no acceptable C compiler

Tags: node.js

I am working on a hostgator linux server through SSH trying to install and use node.js.  I followed the instructions on [github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation), specifically this section.

> tar -zxf node-v0.6.18.tar.gz #Download this from nodejs.org
>
> cd node-v0.6.18
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

When I type ./configure I get this error.

> Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!
>
> Please Make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed it in a non-standard prefix.

Comment: Does your system have a C compiler on it?

Comment: Not exactly sure how to check, I did a quick search and came up with `gcc -v` to check. I tried that and I get "Permission denied"

Comment: Just checked hostgator's features and apparently for my hosting plan the compilers are disabled. Is there any other way to node.js then?

Comment: You could always use a different host for programming.  Amazon Web Services has a free tier where you can lease a 'micro' server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm speaking with Hostgator support right now to see if they would be willing to help me get setup.

Comment: For those that came here because this is the highest-ranked hit on Google when searching the error message that occur with this problem... you may find [the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444175/openindiana-node-compiling-error-no-c-compiler) is because you need to setup the make process with `CC=gcc ./configure`