# openindiana node compiling error no C compiler

Tags: node.js, openindiana

I am trying to compile node.js on openindiana, below is my Environment,
Even I set gcc path in `.profile`
It keeps saying
No acceptable C compiler found!

```
export PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin:/usr/gnu/bin:$PATH
export PAGER="/usr/bin/less -ins"
export CC=/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin/gcc
export cc=/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin/gcc
```

run

`$ CC=gcc ./configure --with-dtrace --dest-cpu=x64 --prefix=~/local`

or

`$ ./configure --with-dtrace --dest-cpu=x64 --prefix=~/local`

both of them gives following error
Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!

```
    Please make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or
    consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed
    it in a non-standard prefix.
```

`nick@www:~/node-latest-install$ echo $PATH`

/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin/gcc

`nick@www:~/node-latest-install$ which gcc`

/usr/bin/gcc

`nick@www:~/node-latest-install$ which cc`

which: no cc in (/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin/gcc)

`nick@www:~/node-latest-install$ gcc -v`

Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11
Configured with: /home/jt/OI-151A-STABLE/151A-PRESTABLE6/newbuilds/oi-build/components/illumos-gcc/richlowe-gcc-f268959/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc/4.4.4 --with-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++,objc --enable-shared --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.4 (GCC)

Comment: Did you check `config.log` for the detailed error messages that show the commands it tried to run and what errors it got from them?

Comment: @alanc  I didnt find a `config.log`, my current `.profile` is in [THIS GIST](https://gist.github.com/nickleefly/65f78c41772f23894a31)  could you take a look what is wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

if you specify CC variable, make it absolute path to gcc: `CC=/opt/gcc/4.4.4/bin/gcc`. But if compiler is already in PATH, specifying CC shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a stupid answer but have you tried removing it and re-installing it from package manager. GCC that is

Also when did the problem start occurring?  You could use beadm to roll back the OS to the last update or to when you created a 'Restore Point' so to speak.  Check it out, very useful thing to use before running installs.

Comment: I tried re-install `GCC`, this problem occurs from when I installed it